# Axis and Allies 1940 Multinational Defense, AAA and Radar

Tags: axis-and-allies

Background:

1. In Axis and Allies 1940, two powers may occupy the same territory and defend it together.
2. AAA fire first at enemy aircraft, with each AAA capable of firing at up to 3 enemy aircraft--but no more than 1 per plane. Hits are scored on roll of a 1.
3. Radar increases the hit score from "1" to "2 or less".

General question: What happens when two powers are sharing a territory, and one power has radar, and the other power does not?

Possible solution 1: Split the rolls?
Example: UK has Radar and has 1 AAA. The USA shares this same territory, doesn't have radar, and has 1 AAA. Germany is attacking with 5 aircraft. Normally, the total number of AAA present (2) is enough to fire up to 6 aircraft; but since total number of aircraft (5) is lower than 6, only 5 total AAA rolls are permitted. How does the defender split the dice rolls between the radar-AAA and regular-AAA? Possibilities: Radar AAA: 3 / regular: 1; Radar AAA: 2 / regular 2; Radar AAA: 1/ regular. 3;

Possible solution 2: radar presence.
I the above scenario, since at least one unit with radar is present, are all the friendly AAA "upgraded" to two or less? (i.e., all that is needed is at least one radar-AAA). This also means that if the territory is owned by UK, but the AAA present are from the US, then they score a hit on a dice roll of a one.

Possible solution 3: territory ownership?
The rule book doesn't explain it this way, but this solution can solve the question. If the territory is owned by the power that has radar, then all friendly AAA also roll on 2 or less-- even if the only AAA present are from friendly-but-foreign power without radar. The justification is that the AAA units themselves do not have radar, but the territory is equipped with a radar network. But if the territory is owned by a power without radar, then all friendly AAA *do not* hit on a one, regardless if the other power has "radar-capable" AAA.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact wording of the rule that "radar increases the hit score". If there is nothing beyond those words, then it would logically apply to the unit; in your example the Allies have one British AAA that can take up to three radar-assisted shots, leaving the American unit to take the other two without the bonus. (It would be logically possible to decide to take two radar-assisted shots and three 'manual', but this is unlikely in a real game.)